# Highcharts Highmaps How to change value for color axis in map bubble

Tags: highcharts

I built a map bubble with the size of the bubbles according to the variable "z". Now I want to color the bubbles according to the variable "value": see [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Joh_Christ/rd2uve67/3/)

```
    seriesMapping: [
{
  'id': 0,
  'hc-key': 1,
  'kreis': 2,
  'typ': 3,
  'bundesland': 4,
  'einwohner': 5,
  'lat': 6,
  'lon': 7,
  'z': 8,
  'beatmet': 9,
  'standorte': 10,
  'frei': 11,
  'belegt': 12,
  'value': 13,
  'color': 14
}]
```

Unfortunately the colors is linked to variable "z". How can I change that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change the `colorKey` property to `'value'` (`'z'` by default):

```
series: [
  ...,
  {
    type: 'mapbubble',
    colorKey: 'value',
    ...
  }
]
```

---

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/5mbvk93x/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highmaps/series.mapbubble.colorKey